# Regarding splash in Android

Tags: android

For now, the InitialActivity is set as the main activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="true" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.InitialActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
        android:noHistory="true" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.RegisterActivity"
        android:noHistory="true" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainScreenActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

    </activity>
```

After finishing the registration process in the RegisterActivity, quit the application and re-start the app, I want the app to directly go to MainScreenActivity automatically logged in. So here's the part of the InitialActivity class that checks if I am logged in and goes to the MainScreenActivity if I am.

```
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    // check if user is already logged in.
    if(session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to MainScreenActivity.
        Intent intent = new Intent(InitialActivity.this, MainScreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class));
    }
```

So far, I managed to go directly into the MainScreenActivity with the code above, but in this case I miss the splash. How can I modify the code so that I can still see the SplashActivity even after being automatically logged in?

FYI here's the SplashActivity class code.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Handler hd = new Handler();
    hd.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the splashActivity as the launcher activity (it will be launch every time) and I will check in this activity if user is logged or not, depending on the response launch the RegisterActivity or the mainActivity